# Want to build a decision tree when i have 4 categories in my dependent variable

Tags: r, cart, decision-tree

I want to build a decision tree but I have 4 categories(1,2,3,4) in my dependent variable. How can I build? I am familiar with rpart package which can be used for binary dependent variable. I think if we have more categories then we need to build CHAID model. Please suggest.

```
data<-rpart(cluster, indvariable, data=segmentation, control=rpart.control(cp=0.01)
```

Cluster is my dependent variable which has 4 categories.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that doing the multiclass model is any different than binary classification, which you said you already know.

Have you tried it with syntax like this?

```
treemodel = rpart(class ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5, data = df)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.